# CrossValidator.fit() - IllegalArgumentException: Column prediction must be of type equal to ... [array<double>, array<double>], but was type double

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cross-validation, apache-spark-ml

These are the packages I'm using for Python 3.9 and Spark 3.1.1:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssemble, StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MultilabelClassificationEvaluator
```

I'm trying to push a vectorized dataset `df_vec` consisting of 2 columns with default names into the CrossValidator function:

- `features` - vector from VectorAssembler
- `label` - string-indexed numeric from StringIndexer.

This is a **multinomial logistic regression** problem with **6** labels.

`df_vec.printSchema()`:

```
root
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- label: integer (nullable = true)
```

The following steps were run to setup CrossValidator:

```
mlr = LogisticRegression()
mlr_evaluator = MultilabelClassificationEvaluator()
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
    .addGrid(mlr.maxIter, [200]) \
    .build()

cross_validator = CrossValidator(
    estimator=mlr,
    estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
    evaluator=mlr_evaluator
)
```

Trying to fit the CrossValidator object with `df_vec` throws an Exception:

`cv_model = cross_validator.fit(df_vec)`:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed:
Column prediction must be of type equal to one of the following types:
[array<double>, array<double>] but was actually of type double.
```

I was able to confirm that the output with the transformed dataset with mlr() alone had a column `prediction` with type double.

```
x = mlr.fit(df_vec).transform(df_vec)
x.printSchema()

root
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- label: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- rawPrediction: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- probability: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- prediction: double (nullable = false) <---
```

So, CrossValidator seems to expect another format for some reason. If CrossValidator() was granular I could have tried converting the `prediction` column into a vector using `VectorAssembler`, but this is not the case.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator`. You only have one label as an integer, so it does not make sense to use Multi-label evaluator.